# Why numeric enums can be assigned to any number in typescript?

Tags: typescript, enums

I want to know why numeric enums can be assigned to any number. what's different between numeric enums and string-based enums?

```
enum TYPES {
  False = 0,
  True = 1,
  UnKnow = 2,
}

type IType = {
  type: TYPES
}

const demo1: IType = {
  type: 9    // works, hope error: Type 9 is not assignable to type TYPES   
}
```

```
enum COLORS {
  GREEN = 'green',
  RED = 'red',
  YELLOW = 'yellow',
}

type IColor = {
  color: COLORS;
}

const demo2: IColor = {
  color: 'blue'   // error: Type '"blue"' is not assignable to type 'COLORS'.ts(2322)
}
```